# App doesn't exit after redirect to another URL when connected to PC

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, exit

I have condition when I display a message when there is upgrade available and as soon as the user clicks on "Upgrade" button the application is redirected to the given Upgrade URL and application is exited.So, when i press the back key, i will be taken to application list screen.
This works fine when I have no longer connected my device to the PC. But, When am testing the same by connecting the device to PC, the redirection happens well, but on back key press am taken to my application's blank screen.

Here is what happens when "Upgrade" is clicked.

```
case 6:
  //APP_MINOR_UPGRADE_CONFIRM
  switch (dialogResult)
  {
    case 1:
      try
      {
        string url;
        //url = CacheManager.getInstance().getApplicationSettings(CacheManager.APP_APK_UPGRADE_URI);
        url = CacheManager.getInstance().getDataFromConfigFile(CacheManager.APP_APK_UPGRADE_URI);
        if (Utils.isNullString(url))
        {
          url = CacheManager.getInstance().getUpgradeURL();
        }
        DataManager.getInstance().UpdateBadge(false);
        WebBrowserTask browse = new WebBrowserTask();
        browse.URL = url;
        browse.Show();
        game = new Game();
        game.Exit();
        break;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
      }
      finally
      {
       // DataManager.getInstance().CheckCatalogUpgradeStatus();
      }
      break;
    default:
      //delete data from the DB
      ProgressBarControl.displayProgressBar(0, 10, AppResources.DOWNLOADING);
      try
      {
        //byte[] data = (byte[])CacheManager.getInstance().getPersistanceData(Utils.MINOR_UPGRADE_DATA);
        byte[] data = (byte[])CacheManager.getInstance().getDataFromDataFile();
        if (data != null && data.Length > 0)
        {
          DataManager.getInstance().processMyWidgetResponse(data);
          DataManager.getInstance().refresUI();
        }
        DataManager.getInstance().UpdateBadge(false);
        DataManager.getInstance().CheckCatalogUpgradeStatus();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
      }
      finally
      {
        CacheManager.getInstance().deletaFromApplicationCache(Utils.MINOR_UPGRADE_DATA);
      }

      break;

  }
  break;
```

What could be the reason? 
Comments and answers appreciated :)

Comment: Perhaps Zune is interfering somehow? Have you tried closing Zune and running only WPConnect?

Comment: Do you get any exception

Comment: @igrali I haven't done that, will try it and update about it.

Comment: Why dont you log your exceptions?

Comment: @JohnnBlade I do.. who doesn't these days?? :)

Comment: Done!!! I hope u got my invite!!

Comment: Havent seen it yet, what yr skype name, then i will add you to

Comment: Did not receive your skype request, if you give me your skype name i can add you and see if that works